# How to get the logs of a process created with screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a GO application that log text to the console every 10 seconds, I run the application with the command below to keep it running behind the scenes

> $ screen -d -m go run start

I can watch my application running with the command `screen -ls`

But I need a way to see all the logs that have been sent by the GO application

How can I watch the logs of the process ?

Comment: The `screen -ls` command will show you the current `screen` sessions.  If you resume the session running your GO application (`screen -r $SESSION`), does it show what you want?

Comment: `screen` will keep output only to the limit of the scrollback buffer defined by the -h option. If you want to keep all output I would suggest using `tee` to send the output to both the terminal and to a file. You can then either cat the file or use `tail -f` to keep a running output.

Answer (score 0):

To log the output of a process created with `screen`, you can use the `-L` and `-Logfile` options. Here's an example of how to modify your existing command to log the output to a file:

```
screen -L -Logfile logfile.txt -d -m go run start
```

This solution was originally provided by user @Nikhil in
[Save Screen (program) output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614247/7911130)